# Pandas Dataframe find and substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to substring a column of a dataframe based on the result of str.find()

I found the starting point of my string per row an stored it in a new column

```
orders["test"]= orders["meta_data"].str.find("utm_source:").astype(int)
```

now I want to cut out 20 chars after that finding:

```
orders["test2"] = orders["meta_data"].str[orders["test"] : orders["test"]+20]
```

this does not work, I guess because orders["test"] is a series. but I don't know how to extract that particular number from the correct row

right now I get NaN values, but the expected output would be a string of 20chars.

cheers,
E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` and lambda function for processing per rows:

```
orders["test2"] = orders.apply(lambda x: x["meta_data"][x["test"] : x["test"]+20], axis=1)
```

Comment: holy moly this was fast. cannot even accept this as an answer yet :) thanks!!